# Why Openerp7 JS files not working in odoo v11 but worked properly in odoo v10?

Tags: javascript, odoo-10, odoo-11

Javascript files developed in openerp-7 worked properly in odoo 10 but not working in odoo 11 even if odoo 10 has newly modified syntax . Why Is that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a compatibility layer introduced with the new js framework for been able to write code using old js api in Odoo, but that compatibility layer it's not exactly to be compatible with older versions, it's intended to be compatible with the old style of write js code for Odoo widgets.

That means that the compatibility layer just will try to match the old style with the new style, but using the existing widgets and code of the same version. It's not backward compatible to other versions. For example if a widget is removed from v10 into v11 the compatibility layer will not provide you an implementation for that.

Every case need to be analyzed but this is the reason why your old code maybe have stopped to work